# cannot accès to my Model Data base from views.py

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I m learning Django 2.2, I am trying to a model from named sKills base on a parent model named Profile:

But I have this error :

```
DoesNotExist at /skills/
Profile matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/skills/
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Profile matching query does not exist.
```

in Skills => models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
# Create your models here.


class Skill(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}-{}".format(self.user, self.name, self.score)
```

in Skills => Views.py:

```
# Create your views here.
def skill_view(request):
    user_id = request.user.id
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id)

    #profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=user_id)

    SkillFormset = inlineformset_factory(Profile, Skill,fields='__all__',extra=1)

    formset = SkillFormset( instance=profile)

    context = {
        'formset': formset
        }

    return render(request,'skills/add.html',context)
```

In Skills => urls.py:

```
app_name = 'skills'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', skill_view, name='my-skills'),
    ]
```

In Skills => templates =>skills => add.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}my skills{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<form action="" method="POST">
{{formset}}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

In Profile => Models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/img', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['png'])], blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_created(self):
        return self.created.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}-{}".format(self.name, self.get_created)
```

I have Profile user in database I do not understand:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please share the Profile model?

Comment: Most likely profile with user ID actually doesn't exists. Less likelly you're hitting the view with annonimous user.

Comment: @danish_wani I have update the code

Comment: You are using a foreign key to link profiles to users. That means that a user can have more than one profile, which would cause `Profile.objects.get(...)` to fail. You could use a  [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) instead. If you do this, and always create the profile when the user is created, then you can do `request.user.profile` to get the profile of the logged-in user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are looking up on **pk** against **User id**  which is not right as you don't have made the **name** field as **primary_key=True** or inherited from **User** model itself. You have to look up on **name** field of profile

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(name_id=user_id)
```

You can set **name** as **primary key** like this:

```
name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
```

and then you can look up on pk:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

Comment: thanks How to make  the name field as primary_key=True

Comment: name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
For more details visit https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/